# Laravel - Model ID guarding

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Say we have a Topic submission html form which uses the following input fields names:

```
name
text
```

At the controller level we may have written something like this:

```
public function create(Request $request) {
   // Validation logic ...
   Topic::create($request->all());
}
```

What if a client user add an `id` input field:

```
id
name
text
```

Will Laravel populate also the `id` field of the new Model object?
Can I guard the `id` of a Model, or should I use `$request->only()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to use `$fillable` array or `$guarded` for primary key which is `id` by default. Eloquent will not populate primary key when you're using `create()` method.

Comment: That is the answer I was aspecting and that I was searching for. Do you have the link to the documentation to confirm this?

Comment: @LppEdd there is nothing in the docs about this. Even if you'll add `id` to the `$fillable` array, Eloquent will ignore it if you'll use `create()` method.

Comment: I asked because I looked at the source code and create() goes straight to save() without any kind of filters on the default id field. You can look also by yourself

Comment: `create()` uses `fill()` which uses `$fillable` and `$guarded` arrays. But it always uses `save()` which uses `insertAndSetId()` method. You may want to look into the `insertAndSetId()` method to understand how Eloquent creates ID.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel has two ways of achieving this:

```
class Topic extends Model {
       protected $fillable = [
            "name" , "text"
       ];
}
```

Alternatively there is the opposite:

```
class Topic extends Model {
      protected $guarded = [ "id" ];
}
```

`$fillable` contains what is allowed to be mass assigned (via fill or the constructor etc) in the model and `$guarded` contains what should never be mass assigned.

More info at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Alexey, in its answer above, stated the default (automatic) id field is not required to be specified on a guarded or fillable array. Do you usually insert it anyway?

Comment: Not sure if a create would it probably won't fill an incrementing id but may fill a non incrementing one. I would expect `fill` to need it though. You will probably need to check.

Comment: I'm searching the documentation, but it does not go into much details. Looking at the source code, seems create() just use all of the specified attributes, "id" included, as I don't see filters

Comment: @LppEdd in practice if your `id` is auto-incremented then it is ignored by MySQL even if you supply it. (If you're using MySQL).